# How to use pre-designed SQLite in UWP project?

Tags: sqlite, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a SQLite database from another project and I want to use it in a UWP application. But I don't know how to import this database to the project and!

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] specifically.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Like many other questions that are voted to be closed for being too broad, although they, too, are answerable. This question is lacking focus. Which part is the OP having difficulty with? What symptoms did they observe? Are they just having difficulty with copying the file? Issues with integrating it into the build process? Is there some schema update required? Should the character encoding be copied over, or would this be the time to switch to another? All of these questions would be a good question for SO in itself. This OP didn't ask one.

Comment: Have you already known how to use SQlite in Universal app but just not known how to copy the database file? What nuget package of SQLite you want to use? Or actually you only have a database file,and you want to know the rest all?

Comment: @Sunteen Yes I know!!! I can create a new Database and use it but I don't know how to copy database file from project. I use from SQLite.Net-PCL nuget package Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can create a new Database and use it but I don't know how to copy database file from project. I use from SQLite.Net-PCL nuget package.

For how to access an exist file, there are two locations that all apps can access. Details please reference the [file-access-permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

One is `Application install directory`. As @Henk Holterman said, you can import your existed database file into your project by right-click one folder and select Add->Existing item to add your database file to the project. Pay attention the file's `Build action` property need to be set to `content`. Details please see the following picture. [image: Sun.db in Assets folder]

Suppose you already had a database file `Sun.db` added to the Assets folder, and now you can connect to it by the following code( use the SQLite.Net-PCL Nuget Package).

```
  path = Path.Combine(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, @"Assets\Sun.db");
  using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))
  {
  }
```

But this folder is read only. Another location is `Application data locations` which can read/write. You can copy the database file from install directory to the application data directory for using. The following code example is for connecting a database file that in the local folder.

```
  StorageFile file;
  try
  {
      file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Sun.db");
  }
  catch
  {
      StorageFile Importedfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Sun.db"));
      file = await Importedfile.CopyAsync(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
  }
  path = file.Path;

  using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path))
  {
      conn.CreateTable<User>();
  }
```