# How to access Sqlite database file in Xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I have a Xamarin project. In my UWP project's root, I stored a sqlite file that has initial tables my app needs. I set the '**Build Action**' to '**Content**'. All examples I found look for the file in '**ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path**', but when I run the app, there is nothing in that folder. Everything gets created in Debug folder. Should I use a different path for debug and release? How does the storage work? Are apps being sandboxed in UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All examples I found look for the file in 'ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path', but when I run the app, there is nothing in that folder

Yes, the sqlite file you have set is just a Content for the UWP app, we need to copy it to LocalFolder programmatically in the first run. Using [`StorageFile.CopyAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227193.aspx) method to copy file to the specific location

Please see [Sunteen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5620055/sunteen)'s answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38036834/how-to-use-pre-designed-sqlite-in-uwp-project)

> Another location is Application data locations which can read/write. You can copy the database file from install directory to the application data directory for using. The following code example is for connecting a database file that in the local folder......

Comment: I already solved the problem, but since your answer matches my solution, I label it as the answer for other people to get benefit from this.

Answer (score 0):

In general how I completed my one is,

- Make sure you installed [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/#Adding_SQLite_to_WinPhone)
- For Windows apps (UWP, WP8,WP8.1 etc) all content files should be
  stored at root level (no sub folder. Maybe there is a workaround for
  this but It is default). For me this is very messy to store like
  that. Therefore I created a shared project to store sqllite.db and
  images etc. any shared files for all windows applications.
  set Build Action= content and Copy to Output Directory= Do not Copy
- **async way**

  ```
  var sqliteFilename = "myworkout.db3";

  string     path=Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,sqliteFilename);

  var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT();
                  var task = Task.Run(async () => { await CopyDatabase(); });
                  task.Wait();
  ```

  var _sqliteConnectionWithLock = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionWithLock(platform,new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnectionString( path, false));

  var conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() => _sqliteConnectionWithLock);
- **sync code**

  var sqliteFilename = "mydatabase.db3";

  ```
            string path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,
    sqliteFilename);

            var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT();

                var task = Task.Run(async () => { await CopyDatabase(); });
            task.Wait();

             var conn = new SQLiteConnection(platform,path);
  ```