# How can I create a database file with SQLite-net?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using SQLite-net nuget package in my UWP application. I want to create a local database file to use as such:

```
var s = new SQLiteConnection("myDbSQLite.db3", SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
```

But it throws the error:

> Could not open database file: 
>   C:\Path\MyProject\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\myDbSQLite.db3 (Misuse)

I see in other posts they suggest to use `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");` but I don't see that method?

**EDIT**

The code

```
FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
```

Throws the exception:

> UnauthorizedAccessException access to the path is denied

So I think this is a permission issue I am having with UWP. Is there something in the capabilities that I need to set?

Comment: Is it not part of the assembly?

Comment: No, I don't see a method for `SQLiteConnection.CreateFile`. I am using version `1.5.231` of `sqlite-net-pcl`

Comment: Did you use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.uwp/) Nuget package?

Comment: Yes I did use that nuget package

Comment: @Darius, check my link again...

Comment: @Darius also are you sure it's supposed to be `.db3` extension? I think it should be `.db`.

Comment: The code `FileStream fs = File.Create(path)` throws `System.UnauthorizedAccessException access to the path is denied`

Comment: Please make sure you call this method first as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.internal.sqliteengine.usewinsqlite3?view=msdata-sqlite-1.1.0

Comment: Then follow this tutorial https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because creating a file in UWP must be done with the UWP API, if you're going to use this nuget library, you have to accommodate by creating it yourself first:

```
// Create the empty file; replace if exists.
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("myDbSQLite.db3", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

My UWP app is actually part of a Xamarin.Forms app that is using shared code, so if your app is solely UWP there's probably a better library, such as [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.uwp/) one that Codexer referred.

Comment: Why didn't you use the system IO from dot net standards instead. Or does your app have different  IO classes for each platform?

Answer (score 3):

Check your permissions on the folder, and also try using this for the constructor

```
_database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(
     "myDbSQLite.db3", 
     SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | 
     SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex | 
     SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite );
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a folder wher you have write-access to. So please try the following code:

```
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string dbFile = Path.Combine( path, "myDbSQLite.db3");
var s = new SQLiteConnection( dbFile, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create);
```

Comment: Have you checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512257/how-to-access-sqlite-database-file-in-xamarin-uwp?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
 var databasePath = Path.Combine(GetLocalFileDirectory(), "MyData.db");

        try
        {
            // Create the empty file; replace if exists.
            db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath,
                                         SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |
                                         SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex |
                                         SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }


public string GetLocalFileDirectory()
{
    var docFolder = FileSystem.AppDataDirectory
    var libFolder = Path.Combine(docFolder, "Databases");

    if (!Directory.Exists(libFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);
    }
    return libFolder;
}
```